# Error "Snapshot extension registration failed" when connecting nodes

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, private-blockchain

Description.

The error occurred during the process of building an Ethernet private chain, and I found that the node could not connect. The error message in the log is as follows.

```
INFO [07-24|09:06:36.121] Generated state snapshot                 accounts=8893 slots=0 storage=409.64KiB elapsed=857.349ms
INFO [07-24|09:06:46.668] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=42 static=1
WARN [07-24|09:06:50.246] Dropping unsynced node during sync       id=a47f044273165e81 conn=staticdial addr=172.18.0.50:30303 type=Geth/v1.10.7-unstabl...
INFO [07-24|09:06:58.579] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=38 static=1
ERROR[07-24|09:06:59.321] Snapshot extension registration failed   peer=cb5b9771 err="peer connected on snap without compatible eth support"
INFO [07-24|09:07:08.924] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=40 static=1
INFO [07-24|09:07:20.990] Looking for peers                        peercount=1 tried=46 static=1
```

I went searching for a lot of information about `Snapshot extension registration failed`  and `peer connected on snap without compatible eth support` and couldn't find a solution.

What can I do to connect to the node?

I am a beginner in ethereum blockchain, I hope someone can help me, thank you very much.

Comment: That doesn't look like a serious problem your node tries to connect to another and they don't agree on the same protocol so the other node is dropped. It is common that nodes don't agree if they are from different versions.

Comment: i have this with `web3js` too

Answer (score 7):

`ERROR[07-24|09:06:59.321] Snapshot extension registration failed   peer=cb5b9771 err="peer connected on snap without compatible eth support"`

This is an error for the peer you are trying to connect to, not your node

The peer in question is peer `cb5b9771`. Your node is fine, this issue will not stop it from syncing.

Answer (score 3):

set option: `geth --snapshot=false`

Comment: From release notes on v1.10.0: If you are not confident about the snapshot feature, you can disable it in Geth 1.10.0 via --snapshot=false, BUT be advised that we will make it mandatory long term to guarantee a baseline network health.

Answer (score 0):

I meet this error on the first node (bootnode) too. It seems to result from the private network's bootnode trying to connecting to the nodes in its default bootnode list. Nodes can be correctly connected after I clear the bootnode's bootnode list by setting `--bootnodes=`.